# select by nearest date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, select, datediff

i've a performance problem with this query:

```
@event = Event.find_by_sql("
    SELECT * FROM `IdeProNew_development`.`events`
    WHERE device_id = #{session[:selected_cam_id]}
    AND data_type = 'image'
    AND created_at BETWEEN CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date].to_time.beginning_of_day}', DATETIME)
    AND CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date].to_time.end_of_day}', DATETIME)
    ORDER BY abs(CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date]}', DATETIME)- created_at) LIMIT 1
").first
```

i use this to select the nearest event by the "selected_date"...
it's ok but it's very slow because scan all table (it's very big) and sort by the difference between the selected date and the creation date of the record.

i try to use DATEDIFF like this:

```
@event = Event.find_by_sql("
    SELECT * FROM `IdeProNew_development`.`events`
    WHERE device_id = #{session[:selected_cam_id]}
    AND data_type = 'image' AND created_at
    BETWEEN CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date].to_time.beginning_of_day}', DATETIME)
    AND CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date].to_time.end_of_day}', DATETIME)
    ORDER BY abs(DATEDIFF(CONVERT('#{params[:selected_date]}', DATETIME), created_at)) LIMIT 1
").first`
```

but it's not work very well (sometimes give me a wrong result) and it's slow too.

where is my mistake? could i use some type of indexing to make this query fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use active record to do this rather than an SQL query?
Something like this :

```
`@event = Event.where(:device_id => session[:selected_cam_id]).
               where(:data_type => 'image').
               where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?",    
                                 params[:selected_date].to_time.beginning_of_day, 
                                 params[:selected_date].to_time.end_of_day).
               order("created_at DESC").first`
```

I think it's more efficient.

Comment: it's the same thing..... 20-30 seconds to execute the query.... 

how can i use the EXPLAIN command over this query?

Comment: add .explain at the end of the query (after the .first)

Answer (score 1):

You can Also try this

```
     @event = Event.where(:device_id => session[:selected_cam_id])
     .where(:data_type => 'image').to_a
     .select{|i| i.created_at.to_time >= params[:selected_date].to_time.beginning_of_day 
&& i.created_at.to_time <= params[:selected_date].to_time.end_of_day}
.sort{ |x,y| y.created_at  <=> x.created_at}.first
```

Comment: mmm i don't understand this:
.sort_by{|x,y| y.created_at  <=> x.created_at}
what's x and y? and how <=> oparator return back to me the nearest record by date to params selected date?

Comment: Instead of using sort_by use sort method. sort and select are the methods of array object